# Return a value from a SoapUI TestCase

Tags: groovy, thread-safety, soapui

I'm trying to modularize my test cases, so I'm running a shared test case (as a procedure) that does something useful and returns a result value. As I need to pass-in non-string input properties, I have to run the test case from groovy:

```
def findLoopEndTC = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.testCases["TestCase - Find Loop End"]
assert findLoopEndTC != null, "Referred TC not found"

def runContext = new com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToObjectMap()
runContext.put("TestStepContext", context)
def runner = findLoopEndTC.run( runContext, false )
assert runner.status != com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.TestRunner.Status.FAILED : runner.reason
```

I've learned that the test case is run using the SINGLETON_AND_WAIT mode which ensures that the TestCase itself is run in a thread-safe way.
My question is **how to return a value** from the run test case in a thread-safe way?

I tried `runner.getRunContext().getProperty("Result")`, but it seems that the context properties are no longer there. So there seems to be only the "classical" way, `findLoopEndTC.getPropertyValue("Result")`, but this is aparently not thread-safe.
Are there other possibilities?

I use the free version of SoapUI.

Comment: I chose this solution: pass a Map as a parameter in runContext, and set the return value in the map:

    def results = [:];
    runContext.put("results", results);

Comment: Unfortunately, I found that the tc.run() method itself is not thread-safe when run from a load test (this is the main place where the thread-saveness is needed). So it is usable for functional testing only. See my bug-report http://forum.soapui.org/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=21961&sid=5bb191e6d594dabffda35cb43a2d7699

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. If I understand you correctly, this is what you want:

You’ve put the ‘calling’ context into a new context ‘runContext’:

context.get("TestStepContext").put("Results",resultList)

which has been passed in as the context for the test case to be run (synchronously). I’ll call the test case to be run ‘B’:

def runner = findLoopEndTC.run( runContext, false ) //in calling test case

To get something useful back from ‘B’, somewhere in it you need to put a value back into TestStepContext, e.g.:

context.get("TestStepContext").put("Results",resultList) //My results happened to be a list

In the calling test case, the line you need after the call to run the test case is:

def testResults = runContext.get("TestStepContext").get("Results")

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to work this out for the last few days too. I haven't been able to work out how to make it thread safe but I have an alternative approach which I think works pretty well.

I've based it on this http://forum.soapui.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=4681#p15731 suggestion from the SoapUI team. I found with the above solution it was still not thread safe, 99% of the time this worked but I found sometimes it's possible you can have two test cases both breaking out the loop at the same time.

To deal with this I set runningDeleteCar to the the hashcode for the current testRunner when it's broken out of the loop. I then double check this to make sure that some other test case hasn't gone in and changed it, if it doesn't match I just go back to the while loop. This stops the situation of two test cases breaking out at the same time.

This approach basically means only one test case can go through the shared test case at a time.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The solution offered in your link by the SmartBear team may work most of the times, but without real Java locks it'll still fail sometimes. I chose a different approach, but unfortunately found that the tc.run() method itself has even more substantial problems. See my comment above.